# add css classname and remove css classname using jquery based on the screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying add classname and remove classname based on the resolution using jquery.

Here is my Jquery code. In mobile mode I am getting **totopDesk** in desktop mode I am getting **totop_tab** only in tablet mode I am getting correct class. What I am doing wrong here

```
function isMobile(){
    if($(window).width() <= 575){
        return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
 }
function isTab(){
   if($(window).width() > 575 && $(window).width() <= 992){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
 function isDesktop(){
    if($(window).width() >= 992){
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;
      }
  }

$(window).resize(function ()
  {
     if (isMobile()) {
         goMobile()
    }
   else if (isTab()) {
       goTablet()
     } 
    else {
       goDesktop();
     } 
  })

    function goDesktop()
{
    $("#go_btn").addClass("totopDesk");
    $("#go_btn").removeClass("totop_tab");  
    $("#go_btn").removeClass("totop_mob");
}
function goMobile() {
    $("#go_btn").addClass("totop_mob");
    $("#go_btn").removeClass("totopDesk");
    $("#go_btn").removeClass("totop_tab");
}
function goTablet() {
    $("#go_btn").addClass("totop_tab");
    $("#go_btn").removeClass("totop_mob");
    $("#go_btn").removeClass("totop");
    $("#go_btn").removeClass("totopDesk");  
}
```

without Jquery simple using @Media query I am getting this issue

When I am in Tablet mode in the inspect element 48em class got strike out it showing only deskop css

[image]

Comment: why don't you use pure css `@media`

Comment: @ProGu I have a problem with that when i resize the chrome window that is not working as expected

Comment: You could use Web API matchMedia - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia for your breakpoints in your scripts

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine on my end. By the way with how you set up your if clause you don't need the isDesktop() function. If you were to use it note that 992 would return true in both tablet and desktop (wouldn't cause an issue here but still)

Comment: Examples of how to subscribe to changes of media queries are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries 
const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 576px)");
mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', handleIsMobile);

Comment: @alekskorovin I have updated my question that when I am using only media css when I am in tablet mode it still showing desktop css class

Comment: The issue is happening after reloading of the page or when resizing?

Comment: @alekskorovin both it's happening

Comment: As I can see in the isolated environment - https://codepen.io/alekskorovin/pen/oNGzjwP it works fine with adding correct classes, so the issue is probably in the CSS . Could you please provide HTML/CSS parts as well?

Comment: [Your code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/0ngpm52o/).

Answer (score 0):

According to your picture, you have your media query at line 23 in your main.css file, and the rest of your code starting at line 71 in your main.css file. You need to move the media query after the main styles you are trying to change. CSS reads from top to bottom and applies the bottom most styles. Since your media query comes before the main styles, it is not being applied.